# How to align two figure that are next to each other

Tags: graphics, captions, vertical-alignment, minipage

Here is my latex code both picture has same resolution and size but i dont know why alignment is not right.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}

    \includegraphics[width=8.5cm,height=3.5cm]{img/Capture2.PNG}
    \caption{Do you think extracted diagram has helped you to understand the article better?}
    \label{fig:cap1}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}

    \includegraphics[width=8.5cm,height=3.5cm]{img/Capture1.PNG}
    \caption{If students prefer an extracted diagram with keywords before comprehending article in their education.}
     \label{fig:cap2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since the images have the same height, use `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}`

Comment: The images are distorted, the width is too large, the legend sticks into the margin, the fonts are much too small, and the images are bitmaps, no vector images, which can be scaled without loss of quality. Pie chars can also be set by LaTeX, see packages like TikZ, `pgf-pie`, `pstricks`, ...